# VLC controller is not rendering video

Tags: c#, winforms, libvlc, vlc.dotnet

I ma trying to stream a video from this a rtsp url. When I run the application, I do not get any error but the video is not rendering. I can view this stream on other application but not on this one. Please see my code below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vlcControl1 = new VlcControl();
    vlcControl1.BeginInit();
    vlcControl1.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC");
    vlcControl1.VlcMediaplayerOptions = new[] { "-vv" };
    vlcControl1.EndInit();
    //Controls.Add(this.vlcControl1);

    string[] options = { ":network-caching=30" };

    vlcControl1.Play(new Uri("rtsp://Username:Password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif"), options);
}
```

Comment: Why create a new control and why not initialize the properties in the designer? This code never adds the control to the form so it's enver displayed

Comment: I get your point. I'll try that.

Comment: Why did you try *this* code instead of the standard way? Drop the control on the designer, configure it, and call `Play` from an event handler

Comment: I dropped a vlcController in the form and its name is vlcControl1.

Comment: And now you created a second player. Why? Why not just write `vlcControl1.Play` ? The code you posted looks like it was copied from `InitializeControls`

Comment: I know. I'll get rid of the new..

Comment: Get rid of *everything* above `string[] options `

Comment: Best avatar picture for Stack Overflow ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using Vlc.Dotnet, I'd strongly advise you get a hold of a simple sample like [this one](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/develop/src/Samples/Samples.WinForms.Minimal) and go from there.

Also, it's bad practice to develop an application using your installed VLC librairies. Updating your local VLC application will update libvlc for all your apps developed relying on it (one of many reasons why it's a bad idea).

Use this https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/ instead of the dlls in Program Files.

Comment: That is a very sound advice. I’ll use that. Thank you.